# How to get the "iframe" content on android webview?

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I need to get the image inside the iframe. I know the iframe.src, but I can't get the content without refreshing webView by invoking

`webview.loadUrl(iframe.src)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `loadData` method of webview instead of loadUrl

```
 wvSnow.loadData("....iframe html", "text/html", "UTF-8")
```